# PHP: How to create an algorithm to encrypt strings

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption

I want to create an algorithm which is two ways (Encryption and Decryption), I have searched the web for days to find a way to create an algorithm which is using the amount of bytes each character has.

Exaple:

```
$string = "Hello";
$Array =[
'H' => 3827,
'e' => 371,
'l' => 472,
'o' => 182
];
(Encrypt): $string->encrypt->result: "48Hsj4adj373Hdue73"
(Decrypt): "48Hsj4adj373Hdue73"->decrypt->result: "Hello"

//How would I do it?
```

I have found a solution:

```
class c
    {
        function a($k, $w){
            if($w === 0){
                return $k*13;
            }elseif($w === 1){
                $arr = explode(",", $k);
                $string = "";
                foreach($arr as $ke){
                    $var = (int)$ke/13;
                    $string = $string.chr($var);
                }
                if(empty($string)){return "Error";}return $string;
            }
        }
        function e($str){
            $c = str_split($str);
            $string = "";
            foreach($c as $key=>$k){
                $ke = c::a(ord($k), 0);
                $string = $string.(string)$ke.',';
            }
            $string = rtrim($string, ',');
            return $string;
        }
        function d($str){
            return c::a($str, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't create your own algorithm if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Well, this is to learn more. I won't use it to anything, just need to know how I can do it @CharlotteDunois

Comment: If we're talking about ASCII then each character has the same amount of bytes: 1. If you mean UTF-8 then it can be up to 4.

Comment: question edited, got an answer already :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look also at the usual XOR encryption and Feistel encryption method.

```
class FeistelCipherHelper
{
    /**
     * @param     $str
     * @param int $i
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encode($str, $i = 5)
    {
        $len = strlen($str);
        if ($len % 2 !== 0)
        {
            $str = $str.' ';
        }
        $str = str_split($str, 2);
        $hash = '';
        foreach ($str as $chr)
        {
            $l = ord(substr($chr, 0, 1));
            $r = ord(substr($chr, 1));
            FeistelCipherAlgorithm::encode($l, $r, $i);
            $l = chr($l);
            $r = chr($r);
            $hash .= $l.$r;
        }
        $hash = trim($hash, ' ');
        $hash = Base64Url::encode($hash);

        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * @param     $hash
     * @param int $i
     * @return string
     */
    public static function decode($hash, $i = 5)
    {
        $hash = Base64Url::decode($hash);
        $len = strlen($hash);
        if ($len % 2 !== 0)
        {
            $hash = $hash.' ';
        }
        $hash = str_split($hash, 2);
        $str = '';
        foreach ($hash as $chr)
        {
            $l = ord(substr($chr, 0, 1));
            $r = ord(substr($chr, 1));
            FeistelCipherAlgorithm::decode($l, $r, $i);
            $l = chr($l);
            $r = chr($r);
            $str .= $l.$r;
        }
        $str = trim($str, ' ');

        return $str;
    }
}

class XorHelper
{
    /**
     * @param     $str
     * @param     $passw
     * @param     $salt
     * @return int|string
     */
    public static function encode($str, $passw, $salt)
    {
        $str = XorAlgorithm::code($str, $passw, $salt);
        $str = Base64Url::encode($str);

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * @param     $str
     * @param     $passw
     * @param     $salt
     * @return int|string
     */
    public static function decode($str, $passw, $salt)
    {
        $str = Base64Url::decode($str);
        $str = XorAlgorithm::code($str, $passw, $salt);

        return $str;
    }
}

class Base64Url
{
    /**
     * @param string $input
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encode($input)
    {
        $str = strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/', '-_');
        $str = str_replace('=', '', $str);

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $input
     * @return string
     */
    public static function decode($input)
    {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }
}

class XorAlgorithm
{
    public static function code($str, $passw = '', $salt = 'aeJRhN7840Xn')
    {
        $len = strlen($str);
        $gamma = '';
        $n = $len > 100 ? 8 : 2;
        while (strlen($gamma) < $len)
        {
            $gamma .= substr(pack('H*', sha1($passw.$gamma.$salt)), 0, $n);
        }

        return $str ^ $gamma;
    }
}

class FeistelCipherAlgorithm
{
    /**
     * @param $block
     * @param $key
     * @return int
     */
    public static function func($block, $key)
    {
        $val = ((2 * $block) + pow(2, $key));

        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * @param     $left
     * @param     $right
     * @param int $steps
     */
    public static function encode(&$left, &$right, $steps = 5)
    {
        $i = 1;
        while ($i < $steps)
        {
            $temp = $right ^ static::func($left, $i);
            $right = $left;
            $left = $temp;
            $i++;
        }

        $temp = $right;
        $right = $left;
        $left = $temp;
    }

    /**
     * @param     $left
     * @param     $right
     * @param int $steps
     */
    public static function decode(&$left, &$right, $steps = 5)
    {
        $i = $steps - 1;
        while ($i > 0)
        {
            $temp = $right ^ static::func($left, $i);
            $right = $left;
            $left = $temp;
            $i--;
        }
        $temp = $right;
        $right = $left;
        $left = $temp;
    }
}
```